# Adding multiple items to UIScrollView, but can't scroll?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiscrollview

I'm writing a UI for iOS and I need to create a scrolling view of note-type widgets. I'm experimenting with creating a scrollview and adding some UIView objects to it, but for some reason, I can't scroll, am I doing something wrong? Here's what I'm doing:

```
[_testScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

NSUInteger size = 100;
float height = _testScrollView.frame.size.height/10;
float width = _testScrollView.frame.size.width;
float currTop = 0;

CGSize fooSize = CGSizeMake(_testScrollView.frame.size.width, _testScrollView.frame.size.height);
[_testScrollView setContentSize:fooSize];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    double red = ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX);
    double green = ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX);
    double blue = ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX);

    CGRect currFrame = CGRectMake(0, currTop, width, height);
    UIView* testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:currFrame];
    [testView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0]];
    [_testScrollView addSubview:testView];
    currTop += height;
}
```

I would've expected to scroll through the scrollview and be able to go through all of the 100 UIViews added. What am I missing?

Comment: you need to set the content size for your scroll view to the height of all the uiviews. use setContentSize:cgSizeMake(_testScrollView.frame.size.width,size*height) after the for loop

Comment: @Bergasms you should add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the content size for your scroll view to the height of all the uiviews. use

```
setContentSize:cgSizeMake(_testScrollView.frame.size.width,size*height)
```

after the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Just print(Log screen) your height of contentsize in scrollview.there you can see the scrollview height...you need to add heights of all subviews to get  height of contentsize for scrollview...